# Which version of moment.js support react-native v0.38

Tags: react-native, momentjs

I want to use `moment.js` with `react-native v0.38`. But when I install moment.js using following command in terminal.

```
npm install moment
```

Then it shows `DEPENDENCY` error.

So, please guide me which version of `moment.js`, I can use with `react-native v0.38`.

Comment: Take a look on https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment

Comment: Can you paste that error log?

Comment: Because it's weird. moment.js doesn't have any dependency on react. it's just a regular nodejs module. It doesn't matter where you run it.

Comment: @jimmyweb It just show me error with this message `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-native@0.38.0`

Comment: @Jackwills you're doing something wrong then :)

Comment: @jimmyweb I just run the `npm install moment`. What is wrong in this.

Comment: @Jackwills Ok. Try again. In your project run `rm -rf node_modules && npm install && npm install moment -S` and see if it works. If not get back here and we will try something else.

Comment: @jimmyweb I did the same as you said. Now I got error like this... `+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.4.2
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-native@0.38.0
| `-- babel-preset-react-native@1.9.2 
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-native-vector-icons@4.3.0
`

Comment: @Jackwills so just install them: `npm install react react-native react-native-vector-icons -S` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can install moment along with it's dependencies.

> npm install --save moment react-moment

Comment: does it is same as moment.js

Comment: yes, it will also install the necessary components.

Comment: I gone through the document of this, Here I did not found date.fromnow() feature. I mean format date to ago (5 days ago).